# How to change the shape of a numpy matrix as a function of matrix values

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, tensor

I have a 4×6 numpy array

```
x = array([[  0,   0,  50,  55, 500, 550],
           [  0,   1,  60,  65, 600, 650],
           [  1,   0,  70,  75, 700, 750],
           [  1,   1,  80,  85, 800, 850]])
```

I want to transform it to this 2×2×4 array

```
y = array([[[ 50,  55, 500, 550],
            [ 60,  65, 600, 650]],
           [[ 70,  75, 700, 750],
            [ 80,  85, 800, 850]]])
```

That is to say, I want to use the first two columns of *x* as *i*, *j* coordinates and the remainder of the row as a vector in *y* at position *i*, *j*.

```
y[0][0] = array([ 50,  55, 500, 550])
y[0][1] = array([ 60,  65, 600, 650])
y[1][0] = array([ 70,  75, 700, 750])
y[1][1] = array([ 80,  85, 800, 850])
```

I presume there's a clever way to do this in numpy that doesn't require me to write for loops, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Make `y=np.zeros((2,2,4),int)` and then use `x[:0]` and `x[:,1]` as indices to assign `x[:,2:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[  0,   0,  50,  55, 500, 550],
              [  0,   1,  60,  65, 600, 650],
              [  1,   0,  70,  75, 700, 750],
              [  1,   1,  80,  85, 800, 850]])
y = np.zeros((2, x.shape[0]-2, x.shape[1]-2)
y[x[:,0],x[:,1]] = x[:, 2:]
```

You will get:

```
In [17]: y
Out[17]: 
array([[[ 50.,  55., 500., 550.],
        [ 60.,  65., 600., 650.]],

       [[ 70.,  75., 700., 750.],
        [ 80.,  85., 800., 850.]]])
```